# My confusion about default argument values in Python3.6

Tags: python, arguments

Here are two pieces of codes which were under the standard of python3.6. And they are the examples in the docs of python3.6(tutorial, page25).
The first is:

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L
print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))
```

the result:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

the second:

```
def f(a, L = None):
    if L is None:
        L = []
    L.append(a)
    return L
print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))
```

the result:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

So, in the second piece of code, i am confused that after `print(f(1))` was executed, `print(f(2))` would pass `a = 2` and `L=[1]` to the `f()`, but why `f()` didn't get the `L=[1]`?
If `L = None` in the second piece of code defines the `L` to `None` every time when the `f()` was called, but why `L = []` in the first piece of code don't define `L` to `[]`

Comment: The first case has a default *mutable* argument, in the second case the argument is *immutable*

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 0):

Those two examples show how default arguments work behind the scenes:
the first one demostrates that default arguments 'live' inside the function definition. Meaning: that the value for L in the first function will only ever be reset if you overwrite the whole function with a `def` section.

The Same is true for the second implementation BUT since it's None: you have to initialize it while the function body is executed. This leads to a fresh list every time the function is called.

This behaviour can be confusing and lead to strange results which is why i heard from most sources that it is best to avoid the first option and work with `None` default args.

Hope i could clear things up a bit.